# Install my R Package on a public OpenCPU server

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio, opencpu

I've used this [tutorial](http://www.molecularecologist.com/2013/11/using-github-with-r-and-rstudio/) to create R project and upload it to my Git repository.
Now I want to publish this project on a OpenCPU server. As it's said [here](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/remotely-use-r-packages-on-github/), "any R package on Github can be used remotely on OpenCPU through the /ocpu/github/ API."

```
library(devtools)
install_github("user/repository")
```

However, RStudio says that R package cannot be found. As far as I understand, in the first step I had to create R Package instead of R project. But if I do so, I don't know how to upload it to Git.

Any step-by-step tutorial would be highly appreciated. Please consider that this is the first time I am realizing this procedure.

Comment: It's hard to find the problem without a little more detail. Is the R package in the root of the repo? If not, try install_github("user/repository/subdir"). Can you install other github package? Try eg install_github("hadley/httr"). Is devtools install ok? Is Rtools installed ok?

Comment: @jeremycg: Finally I managed to upload R Package to GitHub. Also I installed the package on OpenCPU without errors. But when I call https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/userName/myRepository/R/function, the Browser says "the Package' myRepository' did not successfully install.
Either installation failed or github repository name does not match package name."

Comment: looking at the tutorial you linked, are you sure you made an [R package](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), and not just a project? If you include a link to the repo it would help

Comment: Is your github repository public? Because if it is private you need to configure your opencpu server to be able to access it.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos did you find a solution?